Marginal effects contrasts in R: replicating rms::contrast and simultaneous confidence intervals
Im trying to replicate the rms::contrast function using the marginaleffects package in R, but am having difficulties. Particularly, I would like to request simultaneous confidence intervals for conditional contrasts in marginal effects, but cannot see how this is done. My initial attempt doesn't even seem to get the same results as rms::contrast when just simply computing point wise confidence intervals so I must be doing quite a bit wrong!
Attempted R code:
library(rms)
library(marginaleffects)

set.seed(1)
age <- rnorm(200,40,12)
sex <- factor(sample(c('female','male'),200,TRUE))
logit <- (sex=='male') + (age-40)/5
y <- ifelse(runif(200) <= plogis(logit), 1, 0)
f <- lrm(y ~ rcs(age,3)*sex)

age_vals <- c(30,40,50)

k <- rms::contrast(f, list(sex='male', age=age_vals), list(sex='female', age=age_vals),  type="individual")
                # conf.type="simultaneous")
         
print(k, fun=exp)

comparisons(
    f,
    comparison = "difference",
    variables = "sex",
    newdata = data.frame(age=age_vals),
    transform = exp
  ) 
  


First, your examples do not match because the default scale of predicted values is “fitted” for marginaleffects::comparisons() but “lp” for rms::contrast(). You can change the type argument to get matching results:
library(rms)
library(marginaleffects)

set.seed(1)
age <- rnorm(200,40,12)
sex <- factor(sample(c('female','male'),200,TRUE))
logit <- (sex=='male') + (age-40)/5
y <- ifelse(runif(200) <= plogis(logit), 1, 0)
f <- lrm(y ~ rcs(age,3)*sex)

age_vals <- c(30,40,50)

k <- rms::contrast(f, list(sex='male', age=age_vals), list(sex='female', age=age_vals), conf.type="individual")
print(k, fun = exp)
#   age Contrast S.E.     Lower      Upper    Z Pr(>|z|)
# 1  30  1.29132   NA 0.2526292   6.600606 0.31   0.7587
# 2  40  2.73344   NA 1.0020803   7.456181 1.96   0.0495
# 3  50  9.67841   NA 0.6565387 142.674938 1.65   0.0982
# 
# Confidence intervals are 0.95 individual intervals

comparisons(
    f,
    variables = "sex",
    newdata = data.frame(age=age_vals),
    type = "lp",
    transform = exp
  ) 
#   
# 
#  Term      Contrast Estimate Pr(>|z|)   S 2.5 % 97.5 % age
#   sex male - female     1.29   0.7587 0.4 0.253   6.60  30
#   sex male - female     2.73   0.0495 4.3 1.002   7.46  40
#   sex male - female     9.68   0.0982 3.3 0.657 142.67  50
# 
# Columns: rowid, term, contrast, estimate, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high, predicted_lo, predicted_hi, predicted, age, y 
# Type:  lp

Second, unfortunately there is currently no way to adjust confidence intervals for multiple comparisons automatically in marginaleffects. However, there is a p_adjust argument which allows you to adjust p values instead. But note that the CIs will remain untouched, even if you use p_adjust.

Thank you so much for your prompt reply @Vincent. It’s very helpful. I was hoping your marginaleffects package could do this as I couldn’t find a way to do this in emmeans! (Needed for models outside the rms suite). If you happen to also know the equivalent syntax for emmeans then I would be very grateful! I can get the simultaneous confidence intervals there but not these contrasts of treatment over an interacting continuous covariate.

I do not know the equivalent syntax in emmeans.

No problem @Vincent, I will post a separate question for that!
